# reset value of multiple (but not all) form fields with jQuery in one line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, jquery-1.7

Is it possible to reset multiple form fields in one line, or one hit, with jQuery. Note: I don't want to reset *all* form fields, only a specified whitelist (as below):

```
// reset some form fields                       
$('#address11').val('');
$('#address21').val('');
$('#town1').val('');
$('#county1').val('');
$('#postcode1').val('');
```

Comment: Not sure why your question was downvoted... +1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery (and CSS) selector strings can contain multiple selectors using a comma as a delimiter for sub-selectors:

```
$('#address11, #address21, #town1, #county1, #postcode1').val('');
```

I'd argue that this is *faster* than using a class (ID look-ups should perform in essentially constant time, whereas a class look-up will have to visit every DOM node), but perhaps less maintainable if you're going to want to change which elements get reset.

Comment: `.class` is [faster](http://jsperf.com/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-13070819-reset-value-o) :)

Comment: Interesting, thanks for that. I assume parsing the selector string is what takes longer.

Answer (score 12):

It is better to use a class so you do not have to maintain a long list of ids.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="resetThis" id="address11" />
<input type="text" class="resetThis" id="address21" />
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(".resetThis").val("");
```

Answer (score 6):

If you have a lot of fields i'd label the ones you want to ignore with a class to minimise code:

```
$('#myForm input:not(.ignore)').val('');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('#Form_name select:not(.fixed)').val('');`

Comment: This is the same as @Emissary 's answer